# Is this called "a display stand with a base"?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

[image]

**Note that**: The information on the panel could show menus of a restaurant as the above picture. Or, it could show some instruction that you often see in university or school. Or, people may put some advert on it.

Is this generally called "**a display stand with a base**" in everyday conversation?

Answer (score 1):

"Display stand with base" looks like the description in a catalogue, or an online site like Amazon.

In "conversation" there is more context and you'd probably call this "a stand"  unless having a "base" is particularly important. In fact you probably wouldn't refer to it at all, it is just implied by the context:

> I want to get *something to display the menu on*.

> Can you put the new menu up.

> I'llpost this instruction outside the room.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It describes the object admirably.

Comment: The system has flagged this as low quality perhaps because of the lack of detail. Can you edit it?

Comment: @mdewey I fail to see what more I can say. "A display stand with base" is a perfect description for the object pictured. And the OP's only question was to ask whether that was what it was called. Clearly, for all everyday purposes one might refer to it as a "stand" or a "display stand".